# Failing an entire context with Shoulda Unit Tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, shoulda

Using `shoulda` with `unit/test` I have a context which requires one test to pass before the others are even tried.

Is there a method I can invoke which will fail all following tests in the current context? Or not even run them?

I'm imagining something like:

```
context "My thing" do
  setup do
    my_variable = false
  end

  should "have my_variable as true" do
    assert_or_contextflunk my_variable
  end
end
```

(Obviously this is a pointless example, but you see what I'm trying to do)

Comment: Maybe I need to skip some tests? I've noticed that the unit test produces '0 skipped', but I haven't seen any methods that would skip the remainder of a context based on one test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a pending block to your setup method.

```
setup do
  pending ('This will be tested later')
  my_variable = false
end
```

See the Pending Examples section of http://rspec.info/documentation/ for further.

Comment: I didn't realise shoulda could be used with RSpec too — I'm actually using unit/test and I can't find any mention of `pending` in the documentation for it - sorry!